# Is 'supplantation' an English word?

Tags: meaning, phrase-meaning

A Mexican anthropologist spontaneously used this word in a phrase: "suplantación de la identidad";
that would means something like "identity theft". She was speaking spontaneously to me on the sidelines of an INAH conference.

But is this word 'supplantation' correct? It strikes me a dubious. "suplantación de la identidad"
translates as "supplantation of identity". Wouldn't 'counterfeiting of one's identity' be better?  or simply "identity theft"?

Comment: Identity theft would be the most common term for it in English.

Comment: Right! However this phrase in English seems to refer exclusively to the theft of money. Whereas the antropologist was referring to the routine theft of the images and/or the identities of indigeneous people because publication without permission is a violation of their rights, and daylight robbery of these persons' "inmaterial cultural patrimony"

Comment: *Supplantation* is in some English dictionaries e.g. [MW](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/supplantation) as the noun from "supplant". There seems a three-way question here about the meanings of *suplantación* (in Spanish), *supplantation*, and *identity theft* .

Comment: Of course "suplantación de la identidad" could be correct Spanish even if "supplantation of identity" is not correct English.

Comment: suplantanción de identitad **in Spanish** is identity theft, "inmaterial cultural patrimony" does not exist in English. The  proper term is: "**intangible cultural heritage**". Literal translation almost never works in these contexts.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, yes, 'supplantation' is a word in English. It's the noun formed from the verb ['to supplant'](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/supplant).

> to supplant

means to supersede or replace, eg, "The omicron variant has currently supplanted others as the most common covid virus".

'Supplantation' is an acceptable English word but it is not very common so it sounds a little strange. As I'm typing this, the word is marked as a misspelling, meaning it is not in the spell check dictionary so it is too rare for that. Many words created by affixes are acceptable, whether they are mentioned in a dictionary or not. But like this one, they may sound strange and 'non-word-like)'.

Also, yes, 'suplantación de identidad' means what is referred to as 'identity theft' in English, whether it's for money or for fraud.

Again, yes, 'supplantation of identity' is just... weird. It sounds like some robot facsimile has killed and replaced the original human but no one knows.

So, in the end, you just want to say 'identity theft', not 'supplantation of identity'.

Comment: @HighPerformanceMark oh cripes. fixed.

Comment: supplant is not really a "legal" word in English even though it may be used in this or that legal context.

Comment: Why isn't the actual word, which M-W licenses, given in the quote? Why isn't M-W attributed to?

Comment: @Lambie 'supplant' seems fine to me. Are you saying it is rare in print or rare in speech or only used by lawyers?

Comment: The word is fine. You said: " 'Supplantation' is a legal English word". That is incorrect. It's just a word.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth There's a link to M-W for supplant and it only has quotes for the root word. It's common for dictionaries to have a quote just for the root word and not for the extensions. So we have to rely on native speaker intuition that the extended word 'supplantation' has its compositional meaning and no (or little) extra connotation.

Comment: @Lambie oops, yes should be non-literal. I'm trying to emphasize that it is an accepted word in English. How would 'legitimate' be? Or actually 'accepted'?

Comment: Sure, I would just remove the idea that it is a legal word. These long Latinate words have strange destinies in English whereas they are so common in the Romance languages as they do not have the benefit of the "Germanic" branch, as it were.

Comment: M-W and copyright laws expect quotes to be correctly attributed. // The fact that M-W actually mentions the derived noun is reasonable evidence of wordness. Productivity can't be assumed in specific cases. Chant –/→ chantation.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth 1) Where is there a quote from M-W? Also do you have a reference we could use to properly attribute M-W quotations? 2) Yes, I agree, that mentioning the derived noun is good evidence of wordness, I was drawing a distinction that the fact that one -doesn't- appear doesn't immediately imply non-wordness.

Comment: For *supplantation* the OED has: "1. The dispossession or displacement of a person (or animal) in a position, esp. by treacherous or dishonourable means; an instance of this.  2. The supersession or displacement of one thing by another." with a long citation history for both.